# Angular directives en templateUrl :'from my server'

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular, and I have a little question.

I am rendering my partials fine with the $routeProvider from the server but I cannot figure out if it's possible from a directive ?

like

```
myapp.directive('mySuperDirective', function() {
    return {
       templateUrl: '/my/awsome/partial/on/my/serveur(with jade)'
    }
})
```

is it possible to do that ? did i miss something ?

thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For templateUrl, best practice is to just create a html file for example:

partial.html

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

Directive:

```
myapp.directive('mySuperDirective', function() {
    return {
       templateUrl: 'partial.html'
    }
});
```

If you still want to load the remote file, you can either use, do this using

Strict Contextual Escaping (sce) or load the template file in link function.

Example for sce :

```
 myapp.directive('mySuperDirective', ['$sce',function($sce) {
    return {
      templateUrl: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('http://servername/filename.html')
    };
  }]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! so do you suggest I should put my directives' templates in the assets and so dealing with server views + client views ? Is it the best practice ?

Comment: directive with views is the best and easy practice.  It can exist in same folder or on server, depending on how you design/architect your project.